# How to dynamically byepass validaton on a field in spring-hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

i'm in a suituation where i need to byepass validation constraints on a specific field. and validate other fields. Is it possible to do that in spring-hibernate.
for example i have validation constraints on two fields as shown

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private long userId;

    @NotEmpty("loginId can't be empty")
    @Column(name="login_id")
    private String loginId;

    @NotEmpty("password can't be empty")
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    // getters/setters
}
```

Now, when i update user i don't need to validate the password. because i won't be updated when user is updated.

Comment: You can create a DTO.

Comment: Is this the only solution. If so i would have to create DTO for every scenario.

Comment: Perhaps you want validation groups?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to validate the incoming object on the controller layer by specifying the annotation `@javax.validation.Valid` per individual request parameter. In this way, those fields which have any validation constraint will be automatically validated. For example:

```
@RequestMapping("given-URL")
public void controllerExample(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
   // code
}
```

Comment: can you explain how exactly i should do that?

Comment: my question is not about validating the entity class with constraints on fields. My question is how do I skip a field with validation constraint on it dynamically so that I can validate other fields.